# PHP UUID extension DLL file for windows

Tags: php, windows, uuid

When i tried to connect to Apache Cassandra server using the php code i got an error "Fatal error: Call to undefined function uuid_make()". I can find that PHP UUID extension was missing in PHP installation. Can anyone please suggest from where i can download the DLL file for PHP installation in my Windows 7 Machine.

Comment: I'd appreciate if you marked my answer as correct if it helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there's no .dll file for the PHP UUID extension available online... you need to compile it from source.  It shouldn't be too hard...

Download it here:
http://pecl.php.net/package/uuid

Follow the instructions here:
http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php

You can also install directly from PECL, instructions here:
http://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild

Comment: The PECL package uuid (a.k.a PHP UUID extension) is a wrapper around libuuid from the ext2utils project, which is a Linux-specific library. So, no, you cannot compile it to a DLL from source.

Comment: The comment above claims that it's not possible, but you have accepted that answer. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the PECL UUID extension is OS specific and will only work on Linux (including OS X) or Solaris.

On windows you have a couple of alternative options:

- Check out com_create_guid (http://php.net/manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php) which is a Windows Only PHP function.
- MySQL has a function called UUID (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) which will generate a UUID, use something like "SELECT UUID()" as your SQL query. (I have not tested that this is available on Windows builds, if you do use it please post a reply to let everyone know how you got on)
- If you are not worried about the uniqueness of your UUID (the reason for a UUID is to be as certain as possible that you won't generate two identical values ever in the lifetime of your application) then you could try some pure PHP implementation. It is not the most desirable solutions and I would never do this in production, but it might be enough for your needs - there are plenty out there on the web to use for inspiration.